# EJB SessionContext @Resource property injection by providing setter and getter

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB class which is having

```
@Resource
private SessionContext objSessionContext;
```

will injection works fine if i provide setter and getter for this property.

Answer (score 1):

It will work as before, only location of @Resource annotation matters.

Eventually injection can also be moved to *set* method, if preferred:

```
@Resource
private void setObjSessionContext(SessionContext obj) {
    objSessionContext = obj;
}
```